# Realm Swift iOS7 documentation

Tags: swift, ios7, realm

I was just wondering if there is any written documentation on realm swift for iOS 7, since it is combination of objective c and swift.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for official documentation, just some guidelines so I have a clearer view of what to use.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you post a specific problem area or specific question?

Comment: What is wrong with the official documentation?

Comment: @jovit.royeca no specific problem, just sometimes it takes me some time to found out swift solution of objective c code

Comment: @mttrb the problem is that if you are developing for iOS7 in swift you need to download objective c realm and then convert code from objective c to swift, which is not always perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to Realm Objective-C's documentation guide (https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest) and API documentation (https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api), which is applicable even when used from Swift.

As our installation instructions recommend (https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation), you should also be using [RLMSupport.swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift) which adds some useful helpers to use Realm Objective-C from Swift. That file's source is its best documentation, it's pretty small and should be fairly readable.

Finally, to determine the exact Swift syntax when calling Objective-C methods, I recommend you either use autocomplete, or command-click a `Realm.framework` token from Swift, which should display Xcode's auto-generated Swift interface for the Realm module.

Comment: I searched everywhere but can't find how to get RLMArray from RLMResults since RLMObject.allObjects returns RLMResults, but deleteObject accepts RLMArray.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: You could just iterate over the RLMResults, adding its items to an RLMArray.